# Animated Spider-Man show with apparently unique villains

Tags: story-identification, marvel, cartoon, spider-man

There's an animated Spider-Man series I remember which had villains/opponents which I haven't seen in any other Spider-Man media

The villains I recall are:

- A species of blue, hairy animal-people which live underground. They have axes, which Spider-Man uses to escape when he's tied up by them. Their leader wore purple robes
- A species of potentially extra-terrestrial flowers, which are sapient and have mouths and voices. They have blue petals and purple bodies, and apparently aren't made of protein. They threw Spider-Man into an arena with a giant animal
- A green French guy with a goatee who had hypnotic powers based around showing an eye, and he might have had a name to do with cats
- Once Spider-Man fought a weird toad-lizard with a snake tongue that sounds like a whip

Spider-Man's web shooters always shot entire webs, and he often swung around when there wasn't any obvious thing to hang onto. However, there was a scene in one episode where Spider-Man couldn't swing across a chasm due to not having anything to swing from

I first found it at some point after 2006, but it appeared to be much older than that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the similarities in sentient plants, I suspect that you're looking for the same work as in [Which 1970s Spider-Man cartoon had sentient alternate dimension plants?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/184281/which-1970s-spider-man-cartoon-had-sentient-alternate-dimension-plants), where the answer turned out to be *[Spider-Man 1967](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_(1967_TV_series))*.

> After inadvertently unleashing a giant plant on the city from a seed he found in the house of a missing scientist, Peter Parker travels back in time to 3,000,000 BC in order to find the professor himself. Spotting a great stone city in the distance, Peter quickly doffs his school clothes to reveal the costume of Spider-Man and, after a battle with an amphibious monster, is captured by a tribe of primitive blue giants. Taken prisoner to the city, Spidey discovers that the professor has become the benevolent ruler of giants and asks for help. The scientist reveals he destroyed the plans with radium. He explains that the only way to stop the menace is to steal radium gems from the temple of an evil society of intelligent plant monsters, which were mutated by its radiation and captured the city from its original inhabitants. Spider-Man is knocked out by the plants and put in an arena with 'Goliath', a giant caterpillar-like monster, for the amusement of the Master Vine. After a brief battle, Spider-Man webs up the beast, defeats the plant soldiers and takes the radium gems, which are the eyes of a huge statue. The plant civilization, dependent on the radiation for survival, withers away. Having returned the prehistoric city to its rightful owners, Spider-Man returns to the present and feeds the radium gems to the giant rampaging beast. Unable to absorb so much energy at once, it too withers away, saving the city once again.

The hypnotist associated with cats is likely from "Pardo Presents"

> While on a date with his girlfriend Polly to see the premiere of "Pardo Productions Presents: My Pet" (along with well-to-do socialites and city officials), Peter Parker becomes entangled in a robbery plot by a villain named Pardo who possesses the strange ability to transform himself into pure energy – while taking the form of an enormous black cat. Everybody in the audience is quickly gassed and left hypnotized by a large eye that appears on the theater screen. Only Peter manages to resist the attack due to his spider-powers. With the rest of the patrons staring helplessly at the screen ahead, the mild-mannered college boy peels off his suit and tie to reveal the fighting togs of Spider-Man. Pardo's goons start robbing the audience of their valuables until Spidey intervenes. He enters the giant eye and is trapped in a water tower. However, he cuts his way out. The wall-crawler leads Pardo on a chase across New York to a showdown atop the Brooklyn Bridge. Once there, the giant black cat is electrocuted, leaving only Pardo's clothes behind.

The underground beasts might be "Menace from the Bottom of the World"

> Peter Parker is sent by J. Jonah Jameson to investigate claims by a seismologist that he has detected subterranean voices in an unknown language. Peter reluctantly carries out the assignment after seeing a rival reporter getting the plum job of investigating the disappearance of a bank. Upon hearing the underground voice transmissions at the seismology lab, Peter uses his spider-hearing to determine that these were the people responsible for making the bank disappear and they are plotting to take another one. Quickly donning his Spider-Man costume, Peter races to the next bank to be taken and sees the bank disappear into the ground. Spider-Man descends thousands of feet into the sinkhole left by the bank to investigate. He soon discovers the bank in a strange underground city inhabited by hairy, ape-like humanoids called Molemen. Their leader sends the Molemen at Spider-Man, but he evades them and seizes their leader. He discovers he is an escaped criminal called Mugs Reily who tunneled his way out of prison and has disguised himself as a Moleman to become their leader. When unmasked, the angry Molemen turn against him and the banks are lifted back to the surface.